# Why Record is not deleting from sqlite data base in android

Tags: android

**This is my button code when i press del button it display data is not deleting i think my code is 100% correct then it is happening **

```
btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    try 
    {       
        long num=Long.parseLong(regno.getText().toString());        
        dba.open();
        Boolean check = dba.deleterec(num);
        if (check == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            xmlc.delete(num);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Not Deleted"Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dba.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

});
```

**this my data deleting method**

```
public boolean deleterec(long regno) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&NO for delting of Record"+regno);
    return db.delete(Database_table,KEY_RegNo+"="+regno,null)>0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just deleting the row from database... but you should also refresh the view so that the change you made in the database will show the effect... like.. if you are using a listview to display... then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

after this method

```
 xmlc.delete(num);
```

which makes the listview with fresh data...

Comment: No i am displaying the data in text boxess

Comment: then  call the display method again...so that it gets the data from the database which has been modified...

Comment: i do it as u said raju but diplay's the record that i deleted
when i write pgrogram like this it delte's the whole record 
return db.delete(Database_table,regno,null)>0;

Comment: i got the solution just little bit of change
return db.delete(Database_table,"rowid="+regno,null) > 0;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `KEY_RegNo` is same as with your column name. Also are you sure the record you want to delete exists in database?

Comment: yes its same as my table column name function always returns me false i don't known when i press search button i display's me record its means data is present in database

Comment: Can you post source code of your `dba` class? I don't see any problems in the code you posted, problem must be somewhere else.